Rewrite the flow an autonomous system as the one of a non-autonomous system
This is probably a very stupid question, but I can't convince myself of an answer. Let $X\in \mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be a smooth autonomous vector field, with flow map at time $t$ denoted as $\phi^t_X:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$. Now my question is if we can always find a non-autonomous vector field $Y_t$ such that its time $1$ solution, starting from time $0$, which I denote as $\phi^{0,1}_{Y_t}$, coincides with $\phi^t_{X}$ for every $t$.
I know that if I fix a positive scalar $a\in \mathbb{R}$, it holds that $\phi^{a t}_X = \phi^t_{aX}$ and this depends continuously on $a$ of course. This reasoning would suggest that the natural candidate for $Y_t$ is $Y_t = tX$, but I feel this is not correct. Unfortunately, I don't have a good intuition with non-autonomous systems, so I am asking this here.
